# Applying a Style when two ids are the same as another one (CSS, HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question that asks for me to apply an opacity in a HTML, CSS and JS project that I am currently working on. Here is what they are specifically asking for:

"When rangeTwo or rangeThree has the same value as rangeOne it should have an opacity of 0.5;"

#rangeTwo, rangeThree and rangeOne are all ids in my html document of input tags.

I am not sure how to approach this and do not even know which stylesheet to put this in. It is either CSS or JS. Would I have to create a function?

Comment: CSS is not a programing language so you can't use conditions in it

Comment: Would there be a way to do this through JS?

Comment: Yes, you can add event listener to the `input` or `change` event of the elements and run your `if` that determine the opacity

Comment: Why are the inputs named range?  Are you looking for something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/natelegakis/y5zqwedc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a snippet to possibly do what you're attempting and included some comments in the code to help you understand what is going on.

Run the snippet to see it in action.

```js
//get rangeOne input by its id
var rangeOne = document.getElementById("rangeOne");

//get rangeTwo input by its id
var rangeTwo = document.getElementById("rangeTwo");

//get rangeThree input by its id
var rangeThree = document.getElementById("rangeThree");

//get div by its id
var opacityDiv = document.getElementById("opacityDiv")

//the function below will set all input range values to 10
//when range two or range three values match range one then the blue div will lower its opacity to 0.5
function changeOpacity() {
  rangeOne.value = "10"
  rangeTwo.value = "10"
  rangeThree.value = "10"
  if (rangeTwo.value === rangeOne.value || rangeThree.value === rangeOne.value) {
    opacityDiv.style.opacity = "0.5";
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS for div to show opacity example */

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button below to change opacity of the blue box.</p>
<!--this is where we are calling the changeOpacity function from our javascript -->
<button onclick="changeOpacity();">Click me</button>
<br />
<br />
<input min="0" max="10" type="range" id="rangeOne" />
<br />
<input min="0" max="10" type="range" id="rangeTwo" />
<br />
<input min="0" max="10" type="range" id="rangeThree" />
<br /><br />
<div id="opacityDiv"></div>
```

Comment: `rangeTwo.value || rangeThree.value === rangeOne.value` - this code means: "if rangeTwo has a value that is not zero or the value of rangeThree is equal to rangeOne". This is not what your comment is stating.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've adjusted the snippet.